# How to close current tab and open link in new tab

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I've created an Online Exam application in Asp.net 4.0 in VS2010 with C#
After completion of the Exam, the student gets redirected to **result.aspx** page using `Response.Redirect()`
The problem is that if user clicks the back button then again the timer starts and he can change the  answer.
I want to close that tab after Exam completion so that the users cannot go back again and open the result in new page.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should put more effort while asking question. That I have tried this or some link in support of your question. Other wise there is less changes of it to getting answered.

Comment: You do realize that even by replacing the history, it would still be possible for the person to save the state in some other way besides history? You need to implement the restriction using something server-side, such as in a database or in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this on your exam page and result page. or you can make the result page a modal popup

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">  
   window.onload = window.history.forward(0);  
</script>
```

Comment: can this affect the cookies?

Comment: No, This wont affect any cookies